# Checking a column if it contains a row value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update a flag if a particular value is found in a column. For example if key1 is found in the entire column of key2, then flag is Y, else it is N.

I wrote the query below but it fails:

```
UPDATE dbo.WRK_DATA
SET flag = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.WRK_DATA WHERE key1 = key2) 
                THEN 'Y'
                ELSE 'N' END
```

See table below:

```
key1| key2 | Flag
20a | 10a  | N
45a | 35a  | Y
55a | 45a  | N
45a | 35a  | Y
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also phrase this as an update self join:

```
UPDATE a
SET flag = CASE WHEN b.key2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
FROM dbo.WRK_DATA a
LEFT JOIN dbo.WRK_DATA b
    ON a.key1 = b.key2;
```

Or, if you want to stick with your current approach, then have a look at Gordon's answer.

Comment: This works. Thanks Tim, Gordon and Sameer. Really Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need table aliases:

```
update d1
    set flag = (case when exists (select 1
                                  from dbo.WRK_DATA d2
                                  where d1.key1 = d2.key2
                                 )
                     then 'Y' else 'N'
                end)
    from dbo.WRK_DATA d1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE TABLE #temp
        (
          key1 VARCHAR(3) ,
          key2 VARCHAR(3) ,
          Flag CHAR(1)
        );

    INSERT  INTO #temp
            ( key1, key2, Flag )
    VALUES  ( '20a', -- key1 - varchar(3)
              '10a', -- key2 - varchar(3)
              ''  -- Flag - char(1)
              ),
            ( '45a', -- key1 - varchar(3)
              '35a', -- key2 - varchar(3)
              ''  -- Flag - char(1)
              ),
            ( '55a', -- key1 - varchar(3)
              '45a', -- key2 - varchar(3)
              ''  -- Flag - char(1)
              ),
            ( '45a', -- key1 - varchar(3)
              '35a', -- key2 - varchar(3)
              ''  -- Flag - char(1)
              ),
            ( '45a', -- key1 - varchar(3)
              '45a', -- key2 - varchar(3)
              ''  -- Flag - char(1)
              );

    UPDATE  a
    SET     Flag = CASE WHEN b.key2 = a.key1 THEN 'Y'
                        ELSE 'N'
                   END
    FROM    #temp a
            LEFT JOIN #temp b
                ON a.key1 = b.key2;


    SELECT  *
    FROM    #temp;

    DROP TABLE #temp;
```